# How to access the filesystem of the VM in which docker is run in windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to find a way to enter inside a VM in which docker runs in windows. Actually, I am running Kubernetes cluster inside docker and when I use hostPath Volume Type, the volume is mounted inside a directory in the VM. Can anyone tell me how to use ssh or is there another way to access the VM filesystem in which docker is run. I also want to copy some files into and from the VM folder.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: You could use `sshfs` but this is not very performant. If you need performance, you should set up a NAS in kubernetes, where all the filesystems are stored. From Windows you should then be able to connect to the NAS via any tool that is supported by the NAS. Best would be via Samba, so you could use Windows-Explorer and mounting the NAS as network drive in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Docker Desktop for Windows (with its built-in single-node k8s cluster), you can access the VM by running `wsl --distribution docker-desktop` from the Windows host.

Note that the `docker-desktop` WSL environment has access to all your Windows drives via `/run/desktop/mnt/host` (e.g. `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/` for the `C:\` drive), so if your goal is to mount a directory from Windows into a pod, you can use these paths in your `hostPath` volume spec.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I have noticed is that in my case /mnt/host/c/ is the path in the VM where my c drive has been mounted. This path /run/desktop/mnt/host/ does not exist inside the docker desktop VM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One more thing I have noticed in Kubernetes in persistent volume details, it says that on this path /var/lib/k8s-pvs/persistence-rabbitmq-server-0/pvc-7c1bf15b-7f84-406e-a8d9-0c5d7442bd71 volume has been mounted in docker desktop vm but after typing wsl --distribution docker-desktop command and after going inside vm i am unable to find this folder var/lib/k8s-pvs/persistence-rabbitmq-server-0/pvc-7c1bf15b-7f84-406e-a8d9-0c5d7442bd71

Comment: I think maybe you have told me about the Ubuntu vm which is by default installed on windows. maybe it's not the docker desktop virtual machine.